# How can I use a CMS with my custom website

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, html, content-management-system

I'm going to develop a custom site (my own html/css/js, maybe using vueJS) for a client. She wants to be able to edit the content of her site after, add/delete/update images and text.

If I code the site by myself instead of using visual builders inside wordpress, is she going to be able to edit her site with the wordpress built-in tools or I'm the one that will have to make the changes whenever she needs?

Comment: Typically, just about everything on a Wordpress site is put there using Wordpress admin: choosing the features, selecting a theme, adding and using plugins, etc.  I'm not sure where VueJS would fit in here.  And yes, I assume most of the changes would be made from WP Admin, not from a custom app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would wrap your custom part of the wordpress website into a custom plugin. I'm assuming you can wrap a vuejs app, but I haven't done/ tried that yet. But definitely an inspiring question. I would give that a try.

This tutorial should get you started: [Tutorial to create a custom plugin](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch--net-2668)

Implementing the Vuejs SPA afterwards into that plugin should be manageable...

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  If the site is using Wordpress - and if "extra functionality" is needed - then finding (or writing) a Wordpress plugin is the way to go.  As far as "wrapping VueJS" - that's a bit like the tail wagging the dog.  The OP needs to ask himself - do we really *NEED* VueJS here at all?